# Running a bash script from a cronjob fails with "No such file or directory"

Tags: python, bash, shell, cron, anaconda

I'm trying to run the following bash script which runs a Python program after activating a conda environment.

**send.bash**

```
#!/bin/bash
source activate manage_oam_users
python ~/path/to/script/send.py
source deactivate
```

**crontab**

```
30 * * * * source /path/to/script/send.bash
```

I get the following error from cron, although running `source send.bash` works perfectly. I've also tried using `bash send.bash` which works fine when run manually, but results in the same error when run from cron.

```
/path/to/script/send.bash: line 2: activate: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`activate` and `deactivate` are probably scripts located somewhere an entry in your `$PATH` variable points to. Usually, software installed locally for one user adds statements to your `.profile` file or `.bashrc` that extend your `$PATH` variable so that you can use the software's scripts without using full paths.

While your bash loads `.profile` and `.bashrc` automatically, CRON won't do that. There are at least **two solutions** for this.

### A) Full Paths everywhere

Either you use full paths in the script executed by your CRON job, like this:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
source /path/to/activate manage_oam_users
python $HOME/path/to/script/send.py
source /path/to/deactivate
```

Also use `$HOME` instead of `~`. You can find out the full paths using `which activate` and `which deactivate` in your shell.

### B) Source `.profile` or `.bashrc`

Alternatively you can source your `.profile` (or `.bashrc`; you will have to look which file extends your `$PATH` variable with the anaconda directories) in your CRON tab:

```
30 * * * * source $HOME/.profile; source /path/to/script/send.bash
```

### Extra: What does *source* mean?

> **source** is a Unix command that evaluates the file following the command, as a list of commands, executed in the current context.

– [from Wikipedia, the something something great encyclopaedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source_(command))

A commonly used alias for the `source` command is a single dot (`. /path/to/script`).

[A related, but more generic question can be found on the UNIX and Linux Stack Exchange.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/27289/how-can-i-run-a-cron-command-with-existing-environmental-variables)

Answer (score 1):

Since the cron does not run from the directory in which anaconda is installed, it is unable to find activate. Also your path seems to be missing the root anaconda directory.
Find the location of the activate command and add it to your PATH .

```
which activate
/Users/username/anaconda/bin/activate
```

In your bash_profile add

```
export PATH="/Users/username/anaconda/bin:$PATH"
```

Answer (score 0):

additionally, the directory can be defined to be added automatically

```
script_dir=$(dirname $0)

#file_imports
source $script_dir"/functions.sh"
```