# cron command not found - CentOS 7

Tags: php, linux, laravel, centos

I'm using CentOS 7.

I want to run my laravel commands:

```
* * * * * cd /home/path/ && php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

but when I run above code I got this error message:

> -bash: cpanel3-skel: command not found

Comment: See [Running a bash script from a cronjob not working](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45743633/850848).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to your terminal, ssh into your server, cd into your project and run this command.

```
crontab -e
```

This will open the server Crontab file, paste the code below into the file, save and then exit.

```
* * * * * cd /home/path/ && php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1
```

Now if you want to check the list of cron that are currently running use below command.

```
crontab –l
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add this cron entry to your crontab, not to run it as a command. On CentOS, open crontab on text editor using following command:

```
crontab -e
```

Then add your cron entry `* * * * * cd /home/path/ && php artisan schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1` to the end of the file and save the changes.