# Crontab for Postgresql failing with command not found

Tags: linux, postgresql, amazon-ec2, cron

I'm having some trouble with a cronjob I have set for Postgresql. It reports the error **psql: command not found**. Refer to the error log output below.

FYI, when I run the bash script manually by pasting **/var/opt/tableau/tableau_server/TIL_scripts/FIREPROD-DWH_Daily_Extract.bash** into my CLI and pressing return it starts and completes the job successfully on the remote RDS database and then add's a message to the log.

However, the crontab for the same script starts and then immediately fails. What am I missing here?

**1) Error Log below**

```
/var/opt/tableau/tableau_server/TIL_scripts/FIREPROD-DWH_Daily_Extract.bash: line 1: psql: command not found
/var/opt/tableau/tableau_server/TIL_scripts/FIREPROD-DWH_Daily_Extract.bash: line 2: psql: command not found
```

**2) Contents of FIREPROD-DWH_Daily_Extract.bash file below:**

```
export PGPASSWORD=FIREPRODW@r3h0u11; psql -h 'fireprod-pgsql-rds.testdomain.net' -U 'fireproddbwhadmin' -d 'fireprod-datawarehouse' -c 'select schedules_ldn_daily()'
export PGPASSWORD=FIREPRODW@r3h0u11; psql -h 'fireprod-pgsql-rds.testdomain.net' -U 'fireproddbwhadmin' -d 'fireprod-datawarehouse' -c 'select schedules_tv_daily()'
```

**3) .bashrc file for root user below:**

```
# .bashrc

# Source global definitions
if [ -f /etc/bashrc ]; then
        . /etc/bashrc
fi

# Uncomment the following line if you don't like systemctl's auto-paging feature:
# export SYSTEMD_PAGER=

# User specific aliases and functions
export PATH=/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/opt/tableau/tableau_server/packages/customer-bin.20201.20.0614.2321:/home/ec2-user/.local/bin:/home/ec2-user/bin:/var/opt/tableau/tableau_server/data/tabsvc/services/pgsql_0.20201.20.0614.2321/pgsql/bin
```

**4) echo $PATH displays below:**

```
[root@FIREPROD-02 ec2-user]# echo $PATH
/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/opt/tableau/tableau_server/packages/customer-bin.20201.20.0614.2321:/var/opt/tableau/tableau_server/data/tabsvc/services/pgsql_0.20201.20.0614.2321/pgsql/bin
```

**5) Crontab configured per below:**

```
00 2 * * * /var/opt/tableau/tableau_server/TIL_scripts/FIREPROD-DWH_Daily_Extract.bash >> /home/ec2-user/fireprod-dwh_daily_extract.log 2>&1
00 2 28-31 * * [ $(date -d tomorrow +\%d) -eq 1 ] && /var/opt/tableau/tableau_server/TIL_scripts/FIREPROD-DWH_Monthly_Extract.bash >> /home/ec2-user/fireprod-dwh_monthly_extract.log 2>&1
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Running a bash script from a cronjob not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45743633/running-a-bash-script-from-a-cronjob-not-working)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

crontab has it's own PATH. If you want it to find psql you need to add PATH to top of crontab:

`PATH=/usr/local/bin, etc`

or give the full path to psql in your script.

Comment: Hi Adrian,in between posting and your response, I figured it out. I added the following to my script.             
#!/bin/bash   
PATH="/var/opt/tableau/tableau_server/data/tabsvc/services/pgsql_0.20201.20.0614.2321/pgsql/bin"            
and changed my .bash to a .sh

Comment: but i also tried replacing psql with the full exclusive path /var/opt/tableau/tableau_server/data/tabsvc/services/pgsql_0.20201.20.0614.2321/pgsql/bin/psql and this also worked. So either of the two options worked. Y

Comment: Your comment above suggests that i can also add the path to the crontab file too? Because i have 4 tasks scheduled in my crontab, do i just add this directly above the task i want to path? Will it not cause confusion with other 3 tasks that are scheduled in the crontab file?

Comment: The PATH is put at top of file with MAILTO, SHELL, etc. Nor more then they would get confused when running in the shell as long as their commands are in PATH. I generally just use the full path to the command in the crontab entry.