# Cronjob (Mac OS) not returning ouput and empty log

Tags: python, macos, cron

Running macOS Big Sur (11.5.1) and I am trying to run the following cronjob

```
* * * * * cd /Users/name/Documents/Jobs && /usr/bin/env python test.py >> /Users/name/Documents/Jobs/test.txt
```

I don't know why its not working, my `test.txt` comes out blank and I made sure to give myself permission in the system preferences

Comment: Why do you use `/usr/bin/env`?

Comment: thats where my python is, with anaconda

Comment: Commands are looked up in the `$PATH` environment variable automatically. The only place you ever need to use `/usr/bin/env` is in `#!` lines of scripts.

Comment: Add `2>&1` at the end of the line so that error messages go to the file.

Comment: what should i do about the /usr/bin/env, remove it?

Comment: Yes. It won't fix the problem, though.

Comment: okay, i am receiving an error in the log:

/bin/sh: usr/bin/env: No such file or directory 

i imagine this is because its at the beginning of my script

Comment: You probably need to use the full path to the `python` version you want to use. `cron` doesn't execute your shell startup scripts, so if you've added the directory with `python` to `$PATH` it won't be used in `cron`.

Comment: That error indicates that you left out the first `/` in `/usr/bin/env`

Comment: `which python3` gives me: `/opt/anaconda3/bin/python3` should I use this in the cron-tab line instead?

Comment: Yes, that's what I recommend.

Comment: Bu default, cron jobs don't have any of your normal shell environment set up -- they have a very basic `PATH`, no `PYTHONPATH`, etc. You'll need to either specify explicit paths for nearly everything, or add something to the job to build its environment. See [this previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45743633/running-a-bash-script-from-a-cronjob-fails-with-no-such-file-or-directory).

Comment: `/opt/anaconda3/bin/python3 /Users/sebastianlacayo/Documents/Jobs/testp.py >> /Users/sebastianlacayo/Documents/Jobs/test.txt 2>&1` then